# How remove hair from a model consisting of one mesh

Tags: edit-mode, visibility

I have found this project and would like to make some changes, I would like to remove the hair but I don't know how to do it. I don't want to remove piece by piece, there is a fast trick? [image: 3D]

[image]
https://www.cgtrader.com/items/956315/download-page

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no account there and I'm not going to create one just to download one thing to answer this question. And you should not expect people to do that. Either upload the model here: https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions there or make at least a screenshot of the mesh in _Edit Mode_ so that we can maybe guess from that. Or tell us more details about the model, is it all one mesh and the texture is a single image mapped onto it or does the hair maybe have his own material?

Comment: The model has more mesh and texture! I can eliminate using meshimixer but I don't know how do it in blender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to permanently delete the hair, make sure to keep a duplicate of your character or even of your .blend file.

From the look of it, maybe the mesh of the hair have a dedicated material?

If it's the case, while in Edit mode: you should see the material in the material list, select it, and then below the list hit the <kbd>Select</kbd> button to select all the mesh assigned to that material.

[image: material select]

Otherwise, still in edit mode, hover a mesh part of your hair with your mouse cursor, and press <kbd>L</kbd>, it will select all the linked mesh. Repeat this as many times as needed if your hair mesh is made out of multiple mesh shells.

Once you have your hair's mesh selected, you can press <kbd>X</kbd> → Vertices to delete it.

If you want to remove it only temporarly, then you should probably separate it into a different object by pressing <kbd>P</kbd> → Separate by selection:

[image: separate]

Then in the outliner, disable the hair object's visibility:

[image: outliner hide]